# Getting connection error when I am running Eureka server and Eureka clients

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, microservices, netflix-eureka

**This is Dockerfile for Eureka server**

```
FROM openjdk:16-jdk-alpine
COPY target/EurekaDiscoveryService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar EurekaDiscoveryServer.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","EurekaDiscoveryServer.jar"]
```

**This is Dockerfile for Eureka client**

```
FROM openjdk:16-jdk-alpine
COPY target/ApiGateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ApiGateway.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","ApiGateway.jar"]
```

**This is application.properties file for Eureka server**

```
server.port=8010
spring.application.name=eureka-server
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8010/eureka
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

**This is application.properties for Eureka client**

```
server.port=8082
spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://127.0.0.1:8010/eureka
```

**I am using**

```
-docker run -d -p 8010:8010 eurekaserver command to run Eureka server 
-docker run -p 8082:8082 apigateway command to run Eureka client
```

**I am getting following error:**

> Request execution failed with message: I/O error on GET request for
> "http://localhost:8010/eureka/apps/": Connect to localhost:8010
> [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused; nested exception
> is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
> localhost:8010 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused

Comment: can you check if any of the applications are using 8010 port by using netstat command in case of windows and if yes kill the process and run your docker

Comment: yes I have checked none of other process using port 8010 and if any other process or application uses the port 8010 problem will occure to start eureka server also.

Comment: Can you try to link the containers together so you ensure they exist in the same network? You can do this by specify the "--link <Containername>" parameter. You will need to use Containername as Hostname and the original port as port, not the one you forwarded using the "-p" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**I have fixed error**

I have just check for ip address used by container using `docker inspect <CONTAINER_ID>` I came to know that my docker container of eureka server using ip address as `172.17.0.2` and not ip address of `localhost(127.0.0.1)`

**I was using**

```
docker run -e "eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://172.17.0.2:8010/eureka" -p 8082:8082 apigateway
```

to start my eureka client

So I changed  `eureka.client.serviceurl.defaultZone=http://127.0.0.1:8010/eureka`
to `eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://172.17.0.2:8010/eureka`
and it worked.

**Thanks!!**